# Insert batch and Return full object using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, cockroachdb, namedparameterjdbctemplate

I am trying to do batch insertion to a table and then read full objects back with their newly generated `id`s.

```java
    private List<Customer> saveCustomer(List<Customer> customerList, Long shopId) {
        AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
        SqlParameterSource[] paramsArray = new MapSqlParameterSource[customerList.size()];


        for (Customer customer : customerList) {
            MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
            params.addValue("shop_id", shopId);
            params.addValue("customer_name", pallet.getName());
            params.addValue("email", pallet.getEmail());
            params.addValue("contact_number", pallet.getContactNumber());
            paramsArray[index.getAndIncrement()] = params;
        }

        String sql =
                "INSERT INTO \"Customer\" " +
                        "(shop_id, customer_name, email, contact_number) " +
                        "VALUES (:shop_id, :customer_name, :email, :contact_number) " +
                        "RETURNING id, shop_id, customer_name, email, contact_number ";

        return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.getJdbcOperations().query(sql, paramsArray, new CustomerRowMapper());

    }
```

However, this method gives me following error: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use`. See stack trace below.

```
PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO "Customer" (shop_id, customer_name, email, contact_number) VALUES (:shop_id, :customer_name, :email, :contact_number) RETURNING id, shop_id, customer_name, email, contact_number ]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO "Customer" (shop_id, customer_name, email, contact_number) VALUES (:shop_id, :customer_name, :email, :contact_number) RETURNING id, shop_id, customer_name, email, contact_number  ]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1443)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:669)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:712)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:763)
```

Everything would be fine if I just wanted to do batch insertion without reading it back. Then I would use

```java
namedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, paramsArray);
```

However, I also need to read inserted values back with their `id`s but not sure what `namedParameterJdbcTemplate` method I can use.

TLDR:
I want to do batch insertion and then read inserted rows back using `namedParameterJdbcTemplate` but cannot find the right method for this. Does `namedParameterJdbcTemplate` provide batch insertion and selection in a single method?

Answer (score 2):

I got something to work.

```java
private List<Customer> saveCustomer(List<Customer> customerList, Long shopId) {
    List<Object[]> batch = customers.stream()
        .map(customer -> new Object[] {shopId, customer.getName(), customer.getEmail(), customer.getContactNumber()})
        .toList();

    String sql = "INSERT INTO \"Customer\" " +
                 "(shop_id, customer_name, email, contact_number) " +
                 "values :batch" +
                 "RETURNING id, shop_id, customer_name, email, contact_number ";

    return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql,
        new MapSqlParameterSource("batch", batch),
        new CustomerRowMapper());
}
```

Would love to know if there's a better way

**Note:** each element of each `Object[]` is a parameter getting passed and there's a hard cap of 65535 parameters which can be passed at once

**Edit:**

I've made an improvement to this solution, if you instead convert each column from your pojo to a `java.sql.Array` you can do

```sql
insert into customer (store_id, customer_name, ...)
select * from unnest(:storeIds, :customer_names, ...)
returning ...
```

This solution is more performant doesn't run into the parameter cap

Comment: I raised a feature requset for this to be made simpler/clearer https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/29432

Answer (score -1):

As I can see from the methods of `namedParameterJdbcTemplate` you can't execute batch operation and waiting for something back. What you can do is to execute statement in 1 sql request. Just combine your values if your database supports such syntax:

```
INSERT INTO Customer (shop_id, customer_name, email, contact_number)
VALUES
    (value_list_1),
    (value_list_2),
    ...
    (value_list_n);
```

Then just use `JDBCTemplate.update` with the GeneratedKeyHolder argument. This might help you: [identity from sql insert via jdbctemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665846/identity-from-sql-insert-via-jdbctemplate)