# How to get the Primary Key when doing Batch Update in Spring Jdbc NamedParameterJdbcTemplate?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

I am working on **Spring Batch and Spring Jdbc** where I'm using **NamedParameterJdbcTemplate's** `batchUpdate` to insert the record into DB and once the records are inserted I want to get the Primary Keys of all inserted records..

Is there any way to get the generated Primary Keys?

```
List<Person> persons = Arrays.asList(
        Person.create("Dana", "Whitley", "464 Gorsuch Drive"),
        Person.create("Robin", "Cash", "64 Zella Park")
);

String sql = "insert into Person (first_Name, Last_Name, Address) " +
        "values (:firstName, :lastName, :address)";

List<Map<String, Object>> batchValues = new ArrayList<>(persons.size());
for (Person person : persons) {
    batchValues.add(
            new MapSqlParameterSource("firstName", person.getFirstName())
                    .addValue("lastName", person.getLastName())
                    .addValue("address", person.getAddress())
                    .getValues());
}

int[] updateCounts = namedParamJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql,
                           batchValues.toArray(new Map[persons.size()]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74296674/20402396)

The trick is to use `NamedParamJdbcTemplate#query` over `NamedParamJdbcTemplate#batchUpdate` and add `returning <generated_column>` to your insert sql